# Unpack ISO8583 version 93 using jpos

Tags: iso8583, jpos

Hi I am using `JPOS` for packing and unpacking `ISO8583` `version 1993` financial messages.
My sample message is like

```
"1200ð0 €       (1699999900000000003110000000000000000000323221152172201308202147072013082020006504465323221152172FKL0033U        40UNI  CHANDANNAGAR    WEST BENGAL     INDINR041300000^0153001530103422610^356^0.00^0200^32027                0927010185639003MOB005UBNET"
```

Will jpos be able to unpack as the primary bitmap looks like junk.Can i use `iso93ascii.xml` to unpack or anything else required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this blog post that explains why you think the bitmap is junk:

http://jpos.org/blog/2014/09/message-hex-dump/

It is not, problem is you're seeing an ASCII representation, which has unprintable characters.

Get a real binary dump.

Comment: But they send primarybitmap as string like this only.How can i change to hexa

Comment: Please read the provided blog post until you fully understand it.